# How can I display a confirmation message after someone subscribes via simplenews?

Tags: emails

I want to show a message after users submit their email in Simplenews block.

Currently when the user clicks on the subscribe button, the page is refreshed and no message shows ups.

Instead, I prefer to show a message with javascript in modal or something.

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to implement this. And enable the `Simplenews rules` module (a sub-module of [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews)).

Then create a rule like so:

- **Event**: "A user has been subscribed".
- **Action**: "Show a message on the site" (located within "System").

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any response or event that i can show the message in  custom modal(custom javascript)

Comment: i created what you said above and save the rule . but when anonymous user subscribe nothing happen